# Combine mask across all channels

Tags: python, numpy

I have some condition tested in all 3 channels of an image, so I have something like:

```
import numpy as np
check = np.array([[[True, True], [True, False]], [[True, False], [False, False]], [[True, True], [True, True]]])
```

where dimensions are: channel (RGB), height, width.
I want to get 2D array, that shows that all corresponding pixels of different channels are true, so I want to get

```
result = np.array([[True, False], [False, False]])
```

Currently, I'm doing it this ways:

```
result = np.logical_and(check[0, :, :], check[1, :, :], check[2, :, :])
```

But I'm sure there is a more elegant way to do this

Comment: `check` is `3,2,2`. That doesn't correspond to your description

Comment: @mad-physicist It's true. My fault

Comment: @samquar Consequently result should be `np.logical_and(check[0, :, :], check[1, :, :], check[2, :, :])`

Comment: There's an edit button beneath your question. Please use it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [numpy.all](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.all.html?highlight=all#numpy.all) along the axis of interest:

```py
import numpy as np

check = np.array([[[True, True], 
                   [True, False]], 
                  [[True, False], 
                   [False, False]], 
                  [[True, True], 
                   [True, True]]])

np.all(check, axis=0)
array([[ True, False],
       [False, False]])
```

Alternatively you can use a list comprehension on `check` just because you are comparing along the first axis:

```
np.logical_and(*[c for c in check])
array([[ True, False],
       [False, False]])
```